# Как убрать ссылки на карточки товара в WooCommerce? (WordPress)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Нужно сделать ссылки при нажатии на товар неактивными.

Comment: html формируется темой, её надо указать. Кроме того, непонятно, о чём речь - о странице товара, или о странице магазина/категории.

Comment: Кроме того, там обычно не одна ссылка - покажите картинку, где именно надо убрать

Comment: Убрать физически тег <a> или просто запретить переход по onclick?

Comment: @mihdan похоже, ответа не дождёмся. Автор задал вопрос и испарился. Люблю такое))